# PHP. Вывод данных с массива

Tags: php

Всем привет. Возникла задачка, которую не могу решить.
К примеру, есть в массиве 500 данных. И я хочу разбить их по 100. Чтобы в секцию 1 - попадали от 0 до 100, в секцию 2 от 101-200 и так далее. Как это можно решить? Гуглил, но ответ так и не нашел.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Например разбить по 5:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
var_dump(array_chunk($array, 5));
```

Документация http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогли очень!

Answer (score 0):

Если именно из массива, то

```
$array500 = [....]; // Массив из 500 элементов

$section1 = array_slice($array500, 0, 100);
$section2 = array_slice($array500, 100, 100);
// и т.д.
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Вы теряете `100` элемент, поправьте, замените `101` на `100`.

Comment: да, спасибо))))